# Not Seeing HTML audio skipping control in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-audio, web-audio-api

In Chrome I'm able to see the control to be able to skip forwards or backwards in the audio, but in Safari I don't see it.

I've tried both putting the `src` and `type` attributes directly in the audio control and in a child `source` tag, with the same result.

```
<audio controls="" controlslist="nodownload" src="http://myserver:1340/api/v1/media/mediaAsset/s3/groupId/25/variantId/6?token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtleSI6ImJ3QXV0aFBsYXRmb3JtIiwiYXVkIjoiYndBdXRoUGxhdGZvcm0iLCJzdHJhdGVneSI6ImNsb3VkVXNlciIsImlkIjo3NiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiVGVzdCIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiRWRpdG9yIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0LmVkaXRvckBidXNpbmVzc3dpcmUuY29tIiwicG9ydHJhaXQiOiIiLCJjb25uZWN0QWNjb3VudCI6MTAxMDM3NiwidGltZXpvbmUiOi01LCJjaXR5IjoiTmV3IFlvcmsiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODU5NTY3MTcsImV4cCI6MTU4NTk1NjczN30.WnGPJpEnhxhiwmd5mELBmiR1r6lyRzNHtxPTA0XV0YKW-P619yy1OrnnmkdgjiKJNinIRHCrOr_DrCdJbdNj49sVP6J4n7pRcot2c6a1Xpe8K5xTPJ2qyYL_V7N_n5NIsoXNrEYMgHzAjVE3AJ-LVaBbbcFgSu4adTaV0AC1mpCwer7_bVB1J_Sx6oT57xJa_61Ajqd2Gyu712XTy46rp164ad6Iz0PYxxDqGTb7gQ46RvVMocvV4N6tZwdo_zBqev9RPdf1qeYxpieWlXvI3VUMdUCloxdaLiPx72Q6Hc2oHxfs63jOw8esv7QUFtcnzPrYDNq_lggcj4c4s10feg" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: There is no standards to HTMLMediaElement controls UI. The best is still to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

The `controls` attribute in the `audio` tag does not have a value, not even an empty one, and `controlslist` isn't listed as a valid attribute at w3.org, so you should probably avoid that. Some browsers might not be that tolerant to invalid attributes. Therefore, you should just write this tag as `<audio controls src="..." type="audio/mp3">`

In addition, the `type` attribute is only valid in `source`tags  that are children of an `audio` tag.

resource: https://www.w3.org/html/wiki/Elements/audio

Comment: controlslist is [being added to the specs](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2426) and all browsers have to be tolerant with any attributes: if they don't know it, then they ignore it.